# While loop: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been making a function to search through **two lists** and check if a character is in both lists.The error

> "IndexError: list index out of range"

keeps coming up. I put this through python Tutor and it seems like the while loop is totally ignored.I'm coding this search **without using the in function in an if statement**. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
aList = ["B" , "S" , "N" , "O" , "E" , "U" , "T" ]
userInput = "TOE"
userInputList = list(userInput)
letterExists = 0

while (letterExists < len(userInput)):
    for i in aList:
        if (i == userInputList[letterExists]):
            letterExists +=1

if (letterExists == len(userInput)):
        print("This word can be made using your tiles")
```

Comment: use "if i in userInputList"...will work here since length differ here what you are referring in loop

Comment: you don't need to make a list out of the user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code and without trying to do better, I found that a `break` is missing after the incrementation of `letterExists`. Here is the fixed code:

```
aList = ["B" , "S" , "N" , "O" , "E" , "U" , "T" ]
userInput = "TOE"
userInputList = list(userInput)
letterExists = 0

while (letterExists < len(userInput)):
    for i in aList:
        if (i == userInputList[letterExists]):
            letterExists +=1
            break

if (letterExists == len(userInput)):
        print("This word can be made using your tiles")
```

However, a better pythonic solution is the following (same as *xtofl*'s answer):

```
aList = ["B" , "S" , "N" , "O" , "E" , "U" , "T" ]
userInput = "TOF"

a = all([letter in aList for letter in userInput])

if (a):
    print("This word can be made using your tiles")
```

Answer (score 1):

`letterExists < len(userInput)` only guarantees that there is 1 more letter that can be processed, but you may iterate more than 1 time by means of the `for` loop.

By the way, you can write this condition very nicely using `set`:

```
the_set = set(["B", "S", ...])
if(all(x in the_set for x in userInput)):
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python magic and write it like this:

```
len([chr for chr in userInput if chr in aList]) == len(userInput)
```